# Cannot read Excel file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am facing a problem in a project which is uploading excel file through using the CodeIgniter3 and `PHPExcel` library.

The problem occurs when I upload an excel file, the file is uploaded successfully into the folder but it cannot be read. Further, it gives an error message:

> Error loading file "xls_file": Could not open file ./assets/xls_file/ for reading.

So the data couldn't be saved into the database.

I want the system read the file inside the folder of xls_file, why is the system reading the xls_file as folder? My friend told me there may be problem in the URI in CodeIgniter 3, but we don’t know the solution how to fix the problem. Here’s my controller :

```
$fileName = time().$_FILES['file']['name'];
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/xls_file/'; //save excel file in folder
$config['file_name'] = $fileName;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx|csv';
$config['max_size'] = 10000;

$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if(! $this->upload->do_upload('file') )
$this->upload->display_errors();

$media = $this->upload->data('file');
$inputFileName = './assets/xls_file/'.$media['file_name'];

try {
        $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){                  //  Read a row of data into an array                 
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                        NULL,
                                        TRUE,
                                        FALSE);

    //save into the column                              
         $data = array(
            "id_jalan"=> $rowData[0][0],
            "id_kriteria"=> $rowData[0][1],
            "nilai"=> $rowData[0][2],
            "tahun_anggaran"=> $rowData[0][3],
            "penanda"=> $rowData[0][4],
        );
        //save into the tabel
        $insert = $this->db->insert("value",$data);
        //delete_files($media['file_path']);

    }
redirect('page/landing');
```

Comment: Do you know what is the core-reason of error? Check out "read" permission by function "is_readable($file)".
Remove try-catch and show full stack-trace of exception.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use the function @comm1x ?

Comment: @RakaDwija you should check $inputFileName variable. 

if (! is_readable($inputFileName)) die('cant read file, check permissions').

I think, there are no problem with codeigniter, it is file system or file type.

Comment: The result is cant read the file, is there any setting that i have to change ?  I have tried for 2 days just for this case :(

Comment: provide the absoute path  for the file

Comment: How to do that ? The example maybe @pradeep

Comment: <?php  echo FCPATH.'\foldername\filename';?> use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for backslash

Comment: I don't get it, where does the place and how if  I don't know the filename because the filename was automatically generated by the $fileName script. @pradeep

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'xls_file'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

Comment: make sure the path is correct :Print the $config to see the exact result

Comment: now, the error is "Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in C:\xampp\htdocs\simanja\app_data\libraries\PHPExcel\Calculation\Functions.php on line 581"